# Regex Capture group skip escaped strings

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am currently working with Splunk to go through some of my logs and I ran into some regex issues. Right now I have logs in a few different formats. When I constructed the regex I was dumping a JsonConvert.Serialize() to my log which would just dump the json version of my objects which worked well. Now however I am dumping just text and I can't seem to match the regex to my capture group.

```
\{\"line\":\"(?<time>.+)\|(?<log_level>.+)\|(?<Controller>.+)\|(?<Message>.+)\}\"
```

My current RegEx is above and it matches the first two. Note how it ends with curly brace

```
{"line":"18:48:17.990|INFO|PController|Plex event is media.pause}","source":"stdout","tag":"4e263fa2001d"}

{"line":"22:38:47.839|INFO|PController|{\"Id\":\"SMf1bc2466b1\",\"ErrorMessages\":null}","source":"stdout","tag":"b5fcd8b8b5a4"}

{"line":"22:38:47.839|INFO|PController|This is another test","source":"stdout","tag":"b5fcd8b8b5a4"}

{"line":"18:56:37.212|INFO|PController|media.stop","source":"stdout","tag":"4e263fa2001d"}
```

Basically the regex should parse the json from the log and pull the fields out into the specified capture groups. It works well for log #1, and log #2, but it fails on log #3 and log #4 because it doesn't have the ending curly bracket.
[image: ogregex]

I also tried

```
\{\"line\":\"(?<time>.+)\|(?<log_level>.+)\|(?<Controller>.+)\|(?<Message>.+)\"\,
```

but this matches till the end of the "source":"stdout" and not the end of my line tag.
[image]

I am trying to enable the "Message" capture group to have any characters possible which includes quotes, curly brackets, and basically any special character. I'm just trying to pull the Time, LogLevel, Controller, and Message from the full Json string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your group "Message" can either contain a curly bracket with additional quotes or no curly bracket.
You then have to check for both possibilities in your regex:

```
\{\"line\":\"(?<time>.+)\|(?<log_level>.+)\|(?<Controller>.+)\|(?<Message>.+\}|.+?)\"
```

Note that in the case without curly bracket we use a `?` in order to stop at the next quote (lazy expression instead of greedy)
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SQtu4q/1)

Comment: Something seems off with your first line though: the number of closing brackets doesn't match the number of opening ones...

Comment: Hi Tranbi, the regex only matches that expression if it ended with a curly brace and a quote, so I was trying to figure out why it wasn't matching when I got my first message without JSON Serialization and I realized that if I have the Message group end with the curly brace (even if it didn't have a start one) it would match. That was just an example.

And thanks, this was perfect. I think the ? for greedy was something I missed that would've helped a lot.